# How to schedule post processing task after a mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm looking for a simple method to chain post processing code after a map reduce job

specifically, in involves renaming\moving the out files create by `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleOutputs` (the class has limitations on the output file names, so I ca't produce the files directly in the mapreduce job)

The options I know (or think of) are:

- add it in the job creation code - this is what I do now, but I prefer the task will be scheduled by the jobtracker (to reduce the chances of the process being aborted)
- using a workflow engine (luigi, oozie) - but this seems like an overkill for this issue
- using job chaining - this allows chaining mapreduce jobs - it it possible to chain a "simple" task?

Answer (score 1):

Your "simple" task should be a Mapper-only job. Your Map() receives as key the file name and renames the file. For this you have to write your own InputFormat and RecordReader, like in the links, but your RecordReader should not actually read the file, just return the file name in getCurrentKey():

https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-course/source/browse/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wholeFile/WholeFileInputFormat.java?r=3

https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-course/source/browse/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wholeFile/WholeFileRecordReader.java?r=3